# How to create an attribute whch has to be selected by user on view page

Tags: magento-1.9

**Story:**

I have to create a attribute with list of medium to send a product(Courier, eMail, cargo). Some products will have all the three and some will have only two of them. That will be decided while adding a product. So if admin select courier and email for product, in product view page the both have to be displayed in dropdown. Please not the this mode medium is product specific.

**What i tried:**

I have created an attribute and set values as below image[image]:

Then in `\rwd\default\template\catalog\product\view.phtml`,i added below lines:

```
<?php print_r($_product->getAttributeText('card_delivery_medium')); ?>
```

**Result:**

It shows the attribute like below

[image]

But the values are not showing the values selected while adding a product. For this product I selected only Prepaid and email.

Can you suggest whats my mistake.

Comment: please reindex from admin index management,

Comment: @AmitBera yes I did reindexing cleared cache, but its not showing. Need those values to come in a drop down box. For example simple products will be displayed in a drop down box know like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that this can not be don directly. However, below article is helpful to create the things.

http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#catalog/product-configurable.html